# Capture KeyboardInterrupt in pytest in order to Skip Tests

Tags: pytest, keyboardinterrupt

I was wondering if I can skip test during it's execution using KeyboardInterrupt.

I saw that pytest got the hook function:

```
def pytest_keyboard_interrupt(excinfo)
```

which is great, but after it's running, it stops the execution of all the tests, and I want only to skip the specific test that the KeyboardInterrupt came from.

EDIT: I was trying to call pytest from another file and catching KeyboardInterrupt like that:

```
import pytest
try:
    pytest.main(["begin.py", "-vs", "--pdb"])
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pytest.skip("Skipped")
```

But it doesn't work.

I will appreciate any help :)